# Why do I get a NameError when using a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
uppercaseLetters: {
    "A": "_a",
    "B": "_b",
    "C": "_c",
    "D": "_d",
    "E": "_e",
    "F": "_f",
    "G": "_g",
    "H": "_h",
    "I": "_i",
    "J": "_j",
    "K": "_k",
    "L": "_l",
    "M": "_m",
    "N": "_n",
    "O": "_o",
    "P": "_p",
    "Q": "_q",
    "R": "_r",
    "S": "_s",
    "T": "_t",
    "U": "_u",
    "V": "_v",
    "W": "_w",
    "X": "_x",
    "Y": "_y",
    "Z": "_z",
}
input = input("camelCase: ").strip()
for letters in uppercaseLetters:
    input = input.replace(letters, uppercaseLetters[letters])
print("snake_case: ", input)
```

I then get a NameError: `NameError: name 'uppercaseLetters' is not defined`

I'm trying to replace the entries using a loop to turn camelCase into snake case, but the for loop isn't recognizing the dictionary I created.

Comment: you are using `:` instead of `=` to declare the dict!

Comment: Your `uppercaseLetters` is not defined, but only annotated with an (invalid) type hint of a dict shape. Probably you wanted to use `=` instead of `:`. Also note that convention for python variables is `snake_case` and not a `camelCase`, so it should be `uppercase_letters` to conform with PEP8.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something obvious, but I'd been staring at it for an hour already.

Comment: And avoid shadowing builtins: you use `input` and immediately assign to it, causing hard-to-debug issues in future. And you dict could be built as `{letter: f"_{letter.lower()}" for letter in string.ascii_uppercase}` (`import string` before that) instead of enumerating manually, which is error-prone.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Just started learning Python, will try to implement them.

Comment: A hint for your future programming experience: Be aware of the power of Python! The definition of `uppercaseLetters` could be done with a dictionary comprehension and data from the `string` module. If you do `import string`, then it is one line of code: `uppercaseLetters = {c: f'{c.lower()}_' for c in string.ascii_uppercase}`.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the dict with `uppercaseLetters:`, which is invalid. You need to use `=` to define most things, including dictionaries (assuming you are not using dictionary comprehension). So the beginning of your code would look like this:

```
uppercaseLetters = {
    …
}
```